# Group calls in Callkit

Tags: ios, iphone, callkit

I've developed a VoIP app. I'm integrating now with callkit framework. Everything works well except conference.

The situation is the following:

1.) I make a call.
2.) Put first call on hold and make another.
3.) I click Conference button to merge both calls.

If I manually remove hold for first call, automatically second call is on hold.

I've read about CXSetGroupCallAction, but there is no match documentation.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, it will be easy if you can show your code.

Answer (score 2):

Call perform merge call action

```
    let call1UUID = UUID(uuidString: call1.callUUID)!
    let call2UUID = UUID(uuidString: call2.callUUID)!
    let mergeCallAction = CXSetGroupCallAction(call: call1UUID, callUUIDToGroupWith: call2UUID)

    let transaction = CXTransaction()
    transaction.addAction(mergeCallAction)

    callController.request(transaction) { (_) in

    }
```

This will call provider delegate:

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXSetGroupCallAction) {
    // perform merge call here where you merge ports of two call audio i/o
    action.fulfill()
}
```